# What are the explicit matrices of the two 2D irreducible representations of the $C_{6v}$ point group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

The $C_{6v}$ point group has four 1D irreducible representations, and two 2D irreducible representations. The 2D representations are $2\times 2$ matrices.
 I am looking for the explicit matrices of these 2D irreducible representations of the $C_{6v}$ point group. In all of the books and websites I have found, only the character table of the group is given. 
It would suffice if you could describe the procedure or point me to a resource comprehensible by a chemist who is a newbie in group theory.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $C_{6v}$ in group theory is the dihedral group of order $12$, whose representation is given [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups#The_linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups_of_even_degree).

Choose a rotation $\rho$ and a reflection $\sigma$ from $C_{6v}$. They generate the group.

The first two-dimensional irreducible representation sends $\rho$ to $\begin{bmatrix} \frac12 & -\frac{\sqrt3}2 \\ \frac{\sqrt3}2 & \frac12 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\sigma$ to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

The second two-dimensional irreducible representation sends $\rho$ to $\begin{bmatrix} -\frac12 & -\frac{\sqrt3}2 \\ \frac{\sqrt3}2 & -\frac12 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\sigma$ to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.